# Summation and limit formula expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have the following formula in my notes and wondered if someone could explain it to me and show me an example of where it is used.

lim(n->inf)summation(from k=0 to n) $a_k 10^-$$^k$

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{10^k}$$ is what your words look like mathematically, but I'm not exactly sure where your confusion lies?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the base-10 expansion of a number $X\in (-10,10)$. In other words $X=a_0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$